# how to convert exrenal link to internal using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hyperlink, external

i want convert all external link to internal and redirect them
let me show you what i want:
i have an external link to my website like this:

```
<a href ="https://external.com/some text here">link</a>
```

and i converted it to:

```
<a href ="https://mywebsite.com/redirect/https://external.com/some text here">link</a>
OR
<a href ="https://mywebsite.com/redirect=https://external.com/some text here">link</a>
OR somthing like this
```

how can i use .htaccess to make sure when someone opened the link he goes to:

```
https://external.com/some text here
```

i tried this but id didn't worked

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mywebsite.com/redirect/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule matches against the path component of the requested URL only.

Comment: And `/$1` makes little sense - you want to redirect to `https://external.com/...`, and not to `/https://external.com/...`

Comment: @CBroe so there is no way to do this with .htaccess right?
thanks

Comment: Of course there is, you just need to do it without the mentioned mistakes. `RewriteRule ^redirect/(.*)$ $1 [L]` should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^mywebsite.com/redirect/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L]
```

- RewriteRule only matches against the path component of the URL. (And when configured in .htaccess context, the path it checks against never starts with a leading slash, the path to the current directory has been stripped off at this point already.)
- `/$1` would cause a slash *before* the actual substitution URL.

Both fixed, it should simply look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^redirect/(.*)$ $1 [L]
```